# Yii2 validation triggering incorrectly on form with repeated model records

Tags: yii2-validation

I have been working on this all day and this is the first time I have posted here so I hope someone can help me, please.

I have a form where the multiple records for one form are the same model. As a result, I set manually the name and id tags. I place the following code in a foreach loop and generate the tags in the view.

```
// updatemember.php view has these declarations

use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;

...

        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'tab-horizontal', 
                'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
                'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 4 ],
                'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'], 
             ]
             ); 

...

// updatemember calls this subform _claimcontact.php
use kartik\builder\Form;

...

echo Form::widget([ 
    'model'=>$claimcontact,
    'form'=>$form,
    'columns'=>2,
    'attributes'=>[
            'phone_container'=>[ 
                    'label'=>'Phone', 
                    'attributes'=>[ 
                            'phone'=>[
                                        'type'=>Form::INPUT_TEXT, 
                                        'options'=>['name'=>"ClaimContact[$index][phone]", 'id'=>"claimcontact-phone_$index",    ], 
                                        'container' => ['class'=>$col_width],
                                        ],
                        ],
                ],

            'email_container'=>[ 
                    'label'=>'Email', 
                    'attributes'=>[ 
                            'email'=>[
                                        'type'=>Form::INPUT_TEXT, 
                                        'options'=>['name'=>"ClaimContact[$index][email]", 'id'=>"claimcontact-email_$index",   ], 
                                        'container' => ['class'=>$col_width],
                                        ],
                        ],
                ],
        ],
]);

?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set up a rule in the ClaimContact model and the validation triggers correctly the error message and css when I leave the field and it does it properly for record 3 but not for record 2, so that is good as email 3 is blank and email 2 is not blank.

```
[['first_name', 'last_name', 'position', 'phone', 'email' ] , 'required',
```

Unfortunately, when I click the Submit button the filename validation triggers for ALL the records, including the populated filename field. I have attached a sample image.

[Invalid validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BGVh.png)
It seems the Yii validation script generated at the bottom of the source html page has duplicate tags id and name which may be causing the issue.

```
  {"id":"claimcontact-email","name":"email","container":".field-claimcontact-email_0","input":"#claimcontact-email_0","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, 
  {"message":"Email cannot be blank."});}},
```

...

```
  {"id":"claimcontact-email","name":"email","container":".field-claimcontact-email_1","input":"#claimcontact-email_1","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, 
  {"message":"Email cannot be blank."});}},
```

...

```
  {"id":"claimcontact-email","name":"email","container":".field-claimcontact-email_2","input":"#claimcontact-email_2","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {yii.validation.required(value, messages, 
  {"message":"Email cannot be blank."});}},
```

I think if the "id" tag was set to claimcontact-email_0, claimcontact-email_1 and claimcontact-email_2 respectively I bet the validation would work.

I have tried setting inputOptions and the jquery selector option but this does not work.

I have read and used the multiple model article (http://www.yiiframew...ple-models.html) and it worked up to a point but I had a lot of issues with it from another project so I have decided to follow the above approach for more control but there is a bit of a hitch in the validation I need help with, please.

Thanks for taking the time to read my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  One needed to set the name with an $index and then the validation created was unique.

eg.

```
'email_container'=>[ 
            'label'=>'Email', 
            'attributes'=>[ 
                "[$index]email"=>[
                    'type'=>Form::INPUT_TEXT, 
                    'options'=>['name'=>"ClaimContact[$index][email]", 'id'=>"claimcontact-email_$index",   ], 
                    'container' => ['class'=>$col_width],
                    ],
            ],
        ],
```

NOTE: the "[$index]email"

generates this

```
{
  "id":"claimcontact-0-email",
  "name":"[0]email",
  "container":".field-claimcontact-email_0",
  "input":"#claimcontact-email_0","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
      ...
      (attribute, value)) { yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Email cannot be blank."}); 
}
{
  "id":"claimcontact-1-email",
  "name":"[1]email","container":
  ".field-claimcontact-email_1",
  "input":"#claimcontact-email_1","validate":function (attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
      ...
      (attribute, value)) { yii.validation.required(value, messages, {"message":"Email cannot be blank."}); 
}
```

which then results in what I want-validation on only one field.